# Facebook: get url of uploaded photo

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an Iphone application and I am using facebook sdk to post on a user's wall.
I need to create a post with a text and a picture.

For that first I am uploading the picture to the user's profile by using this:

```
//image to post is the UIImage I am uploading
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [self imageToPost], @"picture"   

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}
```

This is working corretly. The `result` I get is in the following format:

```
{
    id = 101586254325716;
    "post_id" = "100004123442691_101551541234190";
}
```

Now I want to post a feed on the user wall containing a text and the image uploaded.

```
//self.facebookStatus is the text I want to post
//imageURL is the url of the image

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              self.facebookStatus, @"message",  
              imageURL, @"picture",
              nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}
```

**Problem:**

I dont know what the `imageURL` should be. I tried to use the `id` or `post_id` I get as a result but it is not working. I alst tried `www.facebook.com/101586254325716` but didn't work either.

How can I get the url of the image I uploaded in order to add it to the wall post?

Thanks

PS: If someone has other ways or hints on posting on a users wall, text + image from the iphone That would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have to use the `object_attachment` parameter and set it to the photo id
and not the `picture` parameter.

Will leave it here in case someone had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In the params dictionary that you're using to post the image add another object, like this:

```
[params setObject:self.facebookStatus forKey:@"message"];
```

that should be enough to post both the picture and the text

Comment: this will post it as a picture and not a wall post or status.

Comment: this don't answer the question