# iphone add text with image posting on facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am posting an image on facebook from iphone using their sample code. And the image is posted fine, the issue is I need to add some text with photo (a default text) , how can I add text with the image I am posting.

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status, NSError *errr) 
 {
     if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {             

         UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon@2x.png"];

         [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:img
                                completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                    [self showAlert:@"Photo Post" result:result error:error];
                                }];


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474462/facebook-get-url-of-uploaded-photo/13475489) and the answers, there you will find how to do it in the user wall and in the user pictures